# When and why socket.send() returns 0 in python?

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

The python3 [socket programming howto](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html#using-a-socket) presents this code snippet

```
class MySocket:
    """demonstration class only
      - coded for clarity, not efficiency
    """

    def __init__(self, sock=None):
        if sock is None:
            self.sock = socket.socket(
                            socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        else:
            self.sock = sock

    def connect(self, host, port):
        self.sock.connect((host, port))

    def mysend(self, msg):
        totalsent = 0
        while totalsent < MSGLEN:
            sent = self.sock.send(msg[totalsent:])
            if sent == 0:
                raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
            totalsent = totalsent + sent

    def myreceive(self):
        chunks = []
        bytes_recd = 0
        while bytes_recd < MSGLEN:
            chunk = self.sock.recv(min(MSGLEN - bytes_recd, 2048))
            if chunk == b'':
                raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
            chunks.append(chunk)
            bytes_recd = bytes_recd + len(chunk)
        return b''.join(chunks)
```

where the send loop is interrupted if the socket [`send`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send) method returns 0.

The logic behind this snippet is that when the `send` method returns '0 bytes sent', the sending side of a socket connection should give up its efforts to send data. This is for sure true for the [`recv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv) method, where zero bytes read for a socket in blocking mode should be interpreted as `EOF`, and therefore the reading side should give up.

However I cannot understand under which situations the `send` method could return zero. My understanding of python sockets is that `send` returns immediately due to buffering at the OS level. If the buffer is full `send` will block, or if the connections is closed at the remote side, an exception is raised.

Finally suppose `send` returns zero without raising an exception: does this really indicate that all future `send` calls will return zero?

I've done some testing (although using only socket connected to `::1` on OS X) and was not able to find a situation in which `send` returns 0.

**Edit**

The HOWTO states:

> But if you plan to reuse your socket for further transfers, you need
>   to realize that there is no EOT on a socket. I repeat: if a socket
>   send or recv returns after handling 0 bytes, the connection has been
>   broken. If the connection has not been broken, you may wait on a recv
>   forever, because the socket will not tell you that there’s nothing
>   more to read (for now).

It is pretty easy to find a situation in which `recv` returns 0: when the remote (sending) side calls [`socket.shutdown(SHUT_WR)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.shutdown), further `recv` on the receiving side will return `0` and not raise any exception.

I'm looking for a concrete example where you can show that receiving 0 zero from `send` indicates a *broken connection* (which will continue to return 0 on send.)

Comment: The HOWTO also explains, "But if you plan to reuse your socket for further transfers, you need to realize that there is no EOT on a socket. I repeat: if a socket send or recv returns after handling 0 bytes, the connection has been broken."

Comment: @J.J.Hakala I tried my best to create a situation where `send` returns after handling 0 bytes, but was not able to find it. I tried almost everything on the receiving side (closing, various combinations of shutdown, etc.) and never the `send` method returned 0. So my question is really which are the exceptional situations where `send` returns 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upon seeing the question I was somehow stunned, because a `send` C call can return 0 bytes and the connection is of course still alive (the socket cannot simply send more bytes at that given moment in time)

- https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/socketmodule.c

I decided to "use the source" and unless I am very wrong (which can always be and often is) this is a bug in the HOWTO.

Chain:

- `send` is an alias for `sock_send`
- `sock_send` calls in turn `sock_call`
- `sock_call` calls in turn `sock_call_ex`
- `sock_call` calls in turn `sock_send_impl` (which has been passed down the chain starting with `sock_send`)

Unwinding:

- `sock_send_impl` returns `true` or `false` (1 or 0) with `return (ctx->result >= 0)`
- `sock_call_ex` returns

  - `-1` if `sock_send_impl` returns `false`
  - `0` if `sock_send_impl` returns `true`
- `sock_call` returns this value transparently.
- `sock_send`

  - returns `NULL` for a `-1` (because an error has been set and an exception will be raised)
  - returns `ctx->result` for `0`from `sock_call`

    And `ctx->result` is the number of bytes written by the C call `send` in `sock_send_impl`.

The chain shows that if `0` bytes have been sent, there is no error and this actually is a potential real life socket situation.

If my logic is wrong, someone please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

I might be wrong, but I think you are looking for an impossible situation...

As @mementum has shown in his answer, it is theoretically possible for a socket to return zero when there is no error, but also no data sent.

However, as shown [elsewhere on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081952/with-c-tcp-sockets-can-send-return-zero) this can only happen in very specific scenarios.  In my experience (and also covered in the comments to the accepted answer) you would only ever get a zero result on a *non-blocking* socket when the network is congested.  Now Python sockets are *blocking* by default, which means that the kernel should wait until there is room to take some more data then return how many bytes were queued.  By definition, this can never be zero.

So, putting it all together, since your snippet doesn't reset the socket type - e.g. using the `set_blocking` function - it is using blocking sockets and so cannot return zero and thus cannot hit the path mementum identified.

This is backed up by the fact that you have been unable to trigger the specific line of code no matter what you do.

Comment: So you agree that the test in the code sample `if sent == 0` is indeed unnecessary?

Comment: As best as I understand it, yes.

Comment: What about receiving a *ix signal during a send or recv? If it happened right at the beginning of a transmission, couldn't that transfer 0 bytes?

Comment: A good question.  Python has logic to retry socket calls on signal interruptions.  See https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ef33712baa2d15878b35a02fbd6ab301c999a5fe/Modules/socketmodule.c#L934