# Why doesn't Python socket.send return the number of bytes sent as the documentation says?

Tags: python, sockets

[According to the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html), Python's `socket.send()`:

> Returns the number of bytes sent.

However, when I use it, it seems to return the byte that was last sent, not the total number of bytes sent.  Consider this code:

```
>>> import socket
>>> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>>> s.connect(('localhost', 12345))
>>> r = s.send(bytes(1))
>>> print(r)
1
>>> r = s.send(bytes(15))
>>> print(r)
15
>>> r = s.send(bytes(150))
>>> print(r)
150
>>> r = s.send(bytes(255))
>>> print(r)
255
>>> r = s.send(bytes(0))
>>> print(r)
0
```

[This SO post seems related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34919846/when-and-why-socket-send-returns-0-in-python), though it doesn't answer my question.

What I'm expecting to see is `r == 1` for every line.

**Solved:**

I got it.  This works:

```
>>> y = bytearray(1)
>>> y[0] = 125
>>> r = s.send(y)
>>> print(r)
1
```

The reason I put `bytes()` in there to begin with is because without it you get:

```
>>> r = s.send(125)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'
```

Comment: Maybe you confuse `bytes` with `chr`?

Answer (score 3):

As the docs for `bytes` say, if the argument is an integer, then it creates a bytearray of that size.

https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytes
https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytearray

Maybe this is what you meant to do?

```
In [26]: r = s.send(b'250')

In [27]: r
Out[27]: 3
```

But even then `b'250'` returns `3`.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion is how Python 2.x and Python 3.x use the `bytes()` function.

In Python3, `bytes(100)` will evaluate to a 100 byte binary array filled in with zero. ([API docs](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytes))
This must be the version of Python you're running as this behavior is consistent with your output.

In Python2, `bytes(100)` will evaluate to `'100'`.
It converts the integer into a string and then assigns the bytearray to that value.
Doing `help(bytes)` on it shows that it is actually the same as the built-in object `str`. So in Python2 `bytes(100)` behaves the same as `str(100)`.

Also in your examples, even according to your expected Python2 behavior, the return value would not always be `1`.
It would be the length of the string, which would be the same as the number of digits in the integer, e.g. `3` for the case of `bytes(100)`.